# Trying to delay a specific function for spawning enemy after a certain amount of time

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

I am making a mole shooter game using pygame. I want my mole to spawn at a random position after every 1 second. I have tried using time.sleep(1.0) but that delays my whole code and thus the game doesn't function properly because of delayed responses. I am moving an aim using the mouse(which also gets affected because of time.sleep) to which i will be adding a click to shoot. I need help with delaying and spawning my mole. I would also like some opinions on how to organize my code to provide various levels of difficulty and a main menu later on.

```
import pygame
import random
import time
from threading import Timer

pygame.font.init()



win_width = 1000
win_height = 710

FPS = 60


screen = pygame.display.set_mode((win_width, win_height))

pygame.display.set_caption("Mole Shooter")



white = (255,255,255)
red = (255, 0, 0)



counter, text = 30, 'Time Left: 30'.rjust(3)
pygame.time.set_timer(pygame.USEREVENT, 1000)

font = pygame.font.Font('freesansbold.ttf', 32)



run = True
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
background = pygame.transform.scale(pygame.image.load('back_land.png'), (win_width, win_height))

aim = pygame.image.load("aim.png")
mole = pygame.image.load("mole.png")


def mole_spawn_easy():

    molex = random.randint(50, 950)
    moley = random.randint(450, 682)

    screen.blit(mole, (molex, moley))


while run:
    screen.blit(background, [0,0])
    ax, ay = pygame.mouse.get_pos()

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False

        if event.type == pygame.USEREVENT:
            counter -= 1
            text = ("Time Left: " + str(counter)).rjust(3)
            if counter > 0:
                time.sleep(1.0);mole_spawn_easy()

            else:
                print("game over")
                break



    screen.blit(aim, ((ax - 32 ),(ay - 32)))



    screen.blit(font.render(text, True, (0, 0, 0)), (32, 48))

    clock.tick(FPS)

    pygame.display.flip()
```

Comment: Related [Spawning multiple instances of the same object concurrently in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62112754/spawning-multiple-instances-of-the-same-object-concurrently-in-python/62112894#62112894)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In pygame exists a timer event. Use [`pygame.time.set_timer()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/time.html#pygame.time.set_timer) to repeatedly create a [`USEREVENT`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html) in the event queue.. The time has to be set in milliseconds:

```py
pygame.time.set_timer(pygame.USEREVENT, 1000) # 1 second
```

Note, in pygame customer events can be defined. Each event needs a unique id. The ids for the user events have to be between `pygame.USEREVENT` (24) and `pygame.NUMEVENTS` (32). In this case the value of `pygame.USEREVENT` is the event id for the timer event.

Receive the event in the event loop:

```py
running = True
while run:

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False

         elif event.type == pygame.USEREVENT:
             # [...]
```

The timer event can be stopped by passing 0 to the *time* argument of `pygame.time.set_timer`.

See also [Spawning multiple instances of the same object concurrently in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62112754/spawning-multiple-instances-of-the-same-object-concurrently-in-python/62112894#62112894).

---

Create a list of `moles` and add a random position to the list in `mole_spawn_easy`:

```py
moles = []

def mole_spawn_easy():
    molex = random.randint(50, 950)
    moley = random.randint(450, 682)
    moles.append((molex, moley))
```

Draw the `moles` in the main application loop:

```py
while run:
    # [...]

    for pos in moles:
        screen.blit(mole, pos)
```

---

See the example:

```py
moles = []

def mole_spawn_easy():
    molex = random.randint(50, 950)
    moley = random.randint(450, 682)
    moles.append((molex, moley))

pygame.time.set_timer(pygame.USEREVENT, 1000)

while run:
    
    ax, ay = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
    
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False

        if event.type == pygame.USEREVENT:
            counter -= 1
            text = ("Time Left: " + str(counter)).rjust(3)
            if counter > 0:
                mole_spawn_easy()
            else:
                print("game over")

    screen.blit(background, [0,0])
    
    for pos in moles:
        screen.blit(mole, pos)
    screen.blit(aim, ((ax - 32 ),(ay - 32)))
    screen.blit(font.render(text, True, (0, 0, 0)), (32, 48))
    
    pygame.display.flip()
    clock.tick(FPS)
```

Comment: Thank you i had to just add del(moles[0]) to remove previous moles from the screen. Now the spawning is working perfectly