# How can I spawn ranctangles in different positions?

Tags: python, pygame, rectangles

```
import pygame
import time
import random
pygame.init()

### VARIABLES ###
# spaceship
MOVEMENT_SPEED = 6
SPACESHIP_WIDTH, SPACESHIP_HEIGHT = 70, 40
RECT_WIDTH, RECT_HEIGHT = 30, 30

# window
GRAVITY = 1
FPS = 60
WIDTH, HEIGHT = 700, 900
WIN = pygame.display.set_mode((WIDTH, HEIGHT))


#colors
WHITE = (255, 255, 255)
BLACK = (0, 0, 0)
RED = (255, 0, 0)
YELLOW = (255, 255, 0)
GRAY = (50, 50, 50)


# spacesgips
SPACESHIP = pygame.image.load('block_game\\Assets\\space_ship.png')
SPACESHIP = pygame.transform.scale(surface=SPACESHIP, size=(SPACESHIP_WIDTH, SPACESHIP_HEIGHT))
SPACESHIP = pygame.transform.rotate(surface=SPACESHIP, angle=90)
# background
BG = pygame.image.load('block_game\\Assets\\background.jpg')
BG = pygame.transform.scale(BG, (WIDTH, HEIGHT))

# random
rand_width = random.randint(0, WIDTH - SPACESHIP_WIDTH) 
rand_height = random.randint(0, HEIGHT - 500)


# rects
RECT_WIDTH, RECT_HEIGHT = 30, 30
rand_rect = pygame.Rect(rand_width, rand_height, RECT_WIDTH, RECT_HEIGHT)


list_colors = [WHITE]#, BLACK, RED, YELLOW, GRAY]
rand_color = random.choice(list_colors)

### VARIANLES ###
```

> This is just how I'm handling the movement so the character doesn't move out the screen.

```
def handle_movement(keys_pressed, spaceship_rect):
    if keys_pressed[pygame.K_a] and spaceship_rect.x > 0:
        spaceship_rect.x -= MOVEMENT_SPEED

    if keys_pressed[pygame.K_d] and spaceship_rect.x < WIDTH - 40:
        spaceship_rect.x += MOVEMENT_SPEED
    
    if keys_pressed[pygame.K_w] and spaceship_rect.y > 600:
        spaceship_rect.y -= MOVEMENT_SPEED

    if keys_pressed[pygame.K_s] and spaceship_rect.y < HEIGHT - 75:
        spaceship_rect.y += MOVEMENT_SPEED
    
    #print(spaceship_rect)
```

> Here I'm planing to do something if I collide with the blocks like, for example, lose a life.

```
# checking for collision
def collision_check(spaceship_rect):
    if spaceship_rect.colliderect(rand_rect):
        print("collide")
```

> This is the way I tried to spawn some rects in some random positions.

```
def drawing_blocks(): 
    pygame.draw.rect(WIN, rand_color, pygame.Rect(rand_rect)) # draw rect
    rand_rect.y += 1
    print(rand_rect.y) 
    
    if rand_rect.y == HEIGHT:
        # and here i want to draw a new block like before
        pass
```

> This doesn't work for me too, I want to spawn 3-5 blocks but in different positions using maybe the random module.

```
def draw_window(spaceship_rect):
    WIN.fill(WHITE) # backgorund
    WIN.blit(BG, (0, 0)) # backgorund
    WIN.blit(source=SPACESHIP, dest=(spaceship_rect)) # spaceship
    
    drawing_blocks()
    pygame.display.update()
```

> main loop

```
def main(): 
    clock = pygame.time.Clock()
    spaceship_rect = pygame.Rect(300, 800, SPACESHIP_WIDTH ,SPACESHIP_HEIGHT)
    
    run = True
    while run:
        clock.tick(FPS)

        for event in pygame.event.get(): # quit funktion
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                run = False
                pygame.quit()

        

        # updateing game 
        keys_pressed = pygame.key.get_pressed() # checking if any key is pressed
        
        
        handle_movement(keys_pressed, spaceship_rect)
        draw_window(spaceship_rect)
        collision_check(spaceship_rect)

    pygame.quit()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

[this is how i want the rectangles to be](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HH1qR.png)

Comment: and what have you tried with the `random` module? also please provide the code in once piece and as a [mre] otherwise it is hard to read or copy paste it for testing.

Comment: Related: [Spawning multiple instances of the same object concurrently in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62112754/spawning-multiple-instances-of-the-same-object-concurrently-in-python/62112894#62112894)

Answer (score -1):

Saving a random rectangle/color in a variable will never work, as the random part of it is never regenerated, it will always remain the same. You should therefore generate a random rectangle everytime you call the function.

```py
def get_rand_rect():
    rand_width = random.randint(0, 660) 
    rand_height = random.randint(0, 400) 
    rand_rect=pygame.Rect(rand_width, rand_height, 30, 30)
    return rand_rect

def drawing_blocks():
    for rect in rand_rects
        pygame.draw.rect(WIN, rand_color, rect) # draw rect
        rect.y += 1
        print(rect.y) 
    
        if rect.y == HEIGHT:
            index=rand_rects.index(rect)
            rects.remove(rect)
            new_rect=get_rand_rect()
            rand_rects.insert(index,new_rect)
```

The following example will draw all rectangles in `rand_rects` ,move them 1 pixel down, and if one of them reaches `HEIGHT`, it will be swapped with a new one. Of course, you should add a `rand_rects` list filled with starting rectangles in your setup.

Comment: i had the exact same idea but now its just drawing random rectangles anywhere everytime the screen refreshes, it should draw just 1-5 of them at the same time and then if one is outside the screen (if rand_rect.y == HEIGHT) new ones respawn. thank you for your response and for helping me with my main project. <333

Comment: @Kelvi919 updated the answer. Is this what you need?

Comment: Just somewhere in your heading, on the place where you defined rand_rect.

Comment: thx this works just as i needed it now i just have to spawn them with a time.sleep code without stoping the game from running. thx again. <3333

Comment: and if you dont mind having 1 friend more on discord add me Kelvi919#4698 ^^

Comment: I'm sorry, don't have discord.

Comment: oh thats okay:)